# C# Extract bitmaps from MP4 stream

Tags: c#, dll, bitmap, stream, mp4

Recently, i searched alot on the internet for a good C# lib to Extract bitmaps from MP4 videos, and i found somethings that were similar to this code, but not to MP4:

```
        VideoStream stream = aviManager.GetVideoStream(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\video.mp4");
        //the video.mp4 is usually .avi or .mpeg
        for (int n = 0; n < stream.CountFrames; n++)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stream.GetBitmap(Position));
            bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\Nehoray\Desktop\Something.png");
            bmp.Dispose;
        }
```

Can anyone give me a library with an easy code like this, just for MP4? :)

Comment: is it possible first convert from mp4 to avi?

Comment: @deadfish - if you just need to play mp4 video as an avi file and dont need to _actually_ convert the container format, you should be able to just rename the file.

Answer (score 3):

I have used Expression Encoder SDK for a similar task. They [declare](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/encoder/thread/3eabf903-b49f-4f92-b508-f28a795d6c90) that MP4 is supported. Take a look at the [AudioVideoFile.GetThumbnail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.audiovideofile.getthumbnail%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use it :)
Is there anyway you could post a code that i could use?

Comment: Their SDK contains an example called `ThumbnailGenerator`, I've copied its sources here - http://codepaste.net/6nzper

Comment: I had to install QuickTime on my PC and add the QTF.dll into my bin folder in order to process MP4

Answer (score 1):

For avi I used to write something like this:

```
string filename = "file.avi";
string storagepath = @"temp\";
static int counter = 0;
MediaDetClass memde;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Create the subfolder
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("temp");

    // Some properities
        counter = 0;
        memde = new MediaDetClass();
        Image img;
        memde.Filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        memde.CurrentStream = 0;
        int len = (int)memde.StreamLength;
        float percent = 0.002f;//how far do u want for a single step

        for (float i = 0.0f; i < len; i = i + (float)(percent * len))
        {

            counter++;
            string fbitname = storagepath + counter.ToString();
            memde.WriteBitmapBits(i, 850, 480, fbitname + ".bmp");
            //img = Image.FromFile(fbitname + ".bmp");
            //img.Save(fbitname + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
            //img.Dispose();
            //System.IO.File.Delete(i + fbitname + ".bmp");
        }
}
```

Library used was: `Interop.DexterLib.dll`, I'm not sure now if you can find it in C# resources. I can share link if you want.

---

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mmokrzycki/Libs) just download RAW file ( There is in C# folder).

Comment: Thanks, actually it helped me for the avi files (i had a problem with the current code)..
I only have 1 problem - im rendering on MP4, because I'm uploading videos to youtube, and AVI is too heavy..
I'll be glad if you'll share a link :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running across this post, checkout this answer: [Get thumbnail image of video file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702031/get-thumbnail-image-of-video-file-in-c-sharp)

One of the posts mention a NuGet package called [NReco.VideoConverter](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.VideoConverter/). This lets you create thumbnails quite easily from an MP4 file:

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(pathToVideoFile, pathToNewThumbnail, locationInSeconds);
```

Comment: This is not availabe for WP 8.1